# Maven dependencies try to reference each other in different module (IllegalAccessError:class <classname> cannot access its abstract superclass)

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

I have maven dependency A which has `com.google.common` as a submodule (transitive dependency?)

However it seems the version under dependency A is quite old, so it's missing some interfaces. On the other hand, I have the most recent `com.google.guava` package which also has `com.google.common`.

The issue seems to arise after building/running the target jar. I get an error that looks like:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.google.common.collect.AbstractListMultimap cannot access its abstract superclass com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap (com.google.common.collect.AbstractListMultimap is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @6368386a; com.google.common.collect.AbstractMapBasedMultimap is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

because I believe the compiler tries to use the module from dependency A as the super class for the `AbstractListMultiMap` from the guava dependency, which doesn't work, since they are in different modules. Note that `AbstractListMultiMap` is not present at all under dependency A.

Is there any way to essentially only use `com.google.guava` ? I tried excluding transitive dependencies from dependency A, but I'm not sure if there are any "transitive dependencies". The pom for dependency A just looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.dreambot</groupId>
  <artifactId>client</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <description>DreamBot 3's client</description>
</project>
```

My current `pom.xml` for my project looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
...

    <!-- dependencies -->
    <dependencies>

...

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dreambot</groupId>
            <artifactId>client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <!-- build jar file with dependencies -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                    <shadedClassifierName>dep-included</shadedClassifierName>
                    <outputDirectory>${dreambot.path}/Scripts</outputDirectory>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
                    

</project>
```

I'm also using maven-shade-plugin to package everything into an uber jar, so I'm guessing it chooses one of the classes for conflicting classnames, leading to the issue.

I tried excluding all transitive dependencies from dependency A, but not sure if there are any to exclude. I also tried reordering some of the dependencies in the pom.xml, but that didn't seem to change much.

I require both dependencies in the project as they are both critical.